# Scala MapReduce Filter

Tags: scala, functional-programming, mapreduce

Is there any way of doing the following in Scala?

Say I have an array of `Double` of size 15:

```
[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,Double.NaN,Double.NaN,110,120,130,140,150]
```

I would like to replace all the `Double.NaN` (from left to right) by the average of the last four values in the array using map reduce. So the first `Double.NaN` gets replaced by 60, and the next `Double.NaN` is replaced by 64 (i.e., the previously calculated 60 at the index 8 is used in this calculation).

So far I have used function type parameters to get the positions of the `Double.NaN`.

Comment: Are you looking for a plain scala solution or are you using MapReduce (the hadoop/bigdata processing framework)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "map-reduce" in this case. It looks rather like a use-case for `scanLeft`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue
val input = List[Double](
  10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,Double.NaN,
  Double.NaN,110,120,130,140,150
)
val patched = input.
  scanLeft((Queue.fill(5)(0d), 0d)){ 
    case ((q, _), x) => { 
      val y = if (x.isNaN) q.sum / 5 else x; 
      (q.dequeue._2.enqueue(y), y)
    }
  }.unzip._2.tail
```

Creates result:

```
List(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 60.0, 64.0, 110.0, 120.0, 130.0, 140.0, 150.0)
```

In general, unless the gaps are "rare", this would not work with a typical map-reduce workflow, because

- Every value in the resulting list can depend on arbitrary many values to the left of it, therefore you cannot cut the dataset up in independent blocks and `map` them independently.
- You are not reducing anything, you want a patched list back

If you are not mapping and not reducing, I wouldn't call it "map-reduce".

By the way: the above code works for any (positive integer) value of "`5`".

Answer (score 0):

Note that averaging the last four values of the first NaN from the given example (50,60,70,80) gives 65, not 60.  The last five will give 60.

Does it have to be a map-reduce?  How about a fold?

```
(List[Double]() /: listOfDoubles)((acc: List[Double], double: Double) => {(if (double.isNaN)
  acc match {
    case Nil => 0.0 // first double in the list
    case _ => {
      val last5 = acc.take(5)
      (0.0 /: last5)(_ + _) / last5.size // in case there's only a last 1, 2, 3, or 4 instead of 5
      }
    }
else double) :: acc}).reverse
```